# How to List All Permissions for SQL Server Fixed Database and Server Roles

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to list all current permissions for `db_owner` and `sysadmin` for SQL Server 2012. I found these SPs:

```
EXEC sp_srvrolepermission 'securityadmin'
EXEC sp_dbfixedrolepermission 'db_owner'
```

However, these are deprecated and only accurate as of SQL Server 2000. Is there an equivalent mechanism to accomplish the same thing today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these roles has an enumerated list of permissions.  db_owner has all permissions in a database, and sysadmin is exempt from permissions checking on both the server and every database.  There are a handful of system procedures that are hardcoded to check for `sa` or perhaps `dbo`.